# Cassandra node does not pull data after cleanup and start

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I deleted by mistake some data files from one of Cassandra nodes.

After that I stopped the said node, removed data, commitlog and saved_caches dirs from it, and started it again.

The node joined and is UN in `nodetool` status and in `OpsCenter`, also it owns 15.3% tokens.

I expect it to start to pull the data from the other nodes, but its data stays on 157.31 KB and it's not doing anything.

In log it can be seen that last log entry was half an hour ago and it was `Handshaking version with DB03/10.2.106.3` (it's its own IP).

How can I balance the data again?

**EDIT**: Cassandra version we use is <strike>2.1</strike> 2.0.12

**EDIT**: in cassandra.yaml there is no entry `auto_bootstrap`, thus it is supposed to be the default `true` setting, according to http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

Comment: please note, there are a number of default settings that don't appear in the cassandra.yaml file but are described in the docs only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `[nodetool rebuild][1]` which Datastax describes as "rebuilds data by streaming from other nodes"